# How does Galaxy Meteor hosting for windows work?

Tags: node.js, windows, meteor, deployment, galaxy

I have a node.js application I have adopted from a more senior developer.  I want to deploy it, and I know it will work because he already deployed it several times.  I am reading these instructions:

https://galaxy-guide.meteor.com/deploy-quickstart.html

I use windows, as did he.

How does deployment work?

Take these instructions:

> Windows If you are using Windows, the commands to deploy are slightly
> different. You need to set the environment variable first, then run
> the deployment command second (the syntax is the same as everything
> you’d put for meteor deploy).
>
> In the case of US East, the commands would be:
>
> $ SET DEPLOY_HOSTNAME=galaxy.meteor.com
> $ meteor deploy [hostname]
> --settings path-to-settings.json

Am I just supposed to go to the source directory on my laptop and run these commands?  What then happens?  Is the source uploaded to their server from my laptop and then their magic takes care of the rest?

What about when I want to make a change to the code?  Do I just do the same thing, poiting to an existing container and, again, they do the magic?

Comment: did you resolve this?

Comment: @Jankapunkt I am still a little shaky on continuous updates.  If I have made changes to the web app, is it really just one command to get the new code running at the same url?

Comment: Bundle building is a well-defined, strongly determined, thus reproducible process. Everything else would be disastrous. You can safely make changes in your app and deploy (including building) it. You can even repeat this with the same codebase, it will result in the exact same bundle. Deploying the bundle is, as I explained below basically a mix of upload, untar, npm install, configure nginx, configure docker etc. which is all automated for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Am I just supposed to go to the source directory on my laptop and run these commands? What then happens? Is the source uploaded to their server from my laptop and then their magic takes care of the rest?

It is not magic. You basically go to your dev root and enter these commands. Under the hood it builds your app for production (including minification and prod flags for optimization) and once complete opens a connection to the aws infrastructure and pushes the build bundle.

See: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/tools/meteor-services/deploy.js

On the server there will be some install and post install scripts that set up all the environment for you and, if there are no errrors in the process, start your app.

These scripts have if course some automation, depending on your account settings and the commands you have entered.

> What about when I want to make a change to the code? Do I just do the same thing, poiting to an existing container and, again, they do the magic?

You will have to rebuild (using the given deploy command) again but Galaxy will take care of the rest.